# change value of @schedule(cron=${cronExp}) in spring without new deployment

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, cron, quartz-scheduler

Hi I am stuck at this place I want to change value of ${cronExp} @schedule(cron=${cronExp}) in spring without need for new deployment

I have code like this in my java class with @EnableScheduling

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0/1 1/1 * ?")
public void abc(){

}
```

Now if I want to change the cron expression after deployment on production 
Currently, I need to re-deploy my application
Is there any way in spring I can do it without deployment?
May using some property file and change the file on server whenever needed 
OR
keep the expression in DB and change it from there 
OR
using quartz scheduling might give me that flexibility

Please suggest some way to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change cron expression by using `@Scehduled` annotation in `spring`.

- You can use [TaskScheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html) instead , like this ,`scheduler.schedule(task, new CronTrigger("cronExp"));`
- This `schedule()` method returns [java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html)
  object which is going to execute next time.
- This(`ScheduledFuture`) you need to save somewhere and if your DB
  `cronExp` value changed then the stored ScheduledFuture has a cancel() method that needs to be called.
- Thus all future schedulers has been cancelled , now we need to create
  new scheduler as we do in the begining `scheduler.schedule(task,new CronTrigger("cronExp"));` with new expression

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I have done the similar implementation before but this time the value for which the next job will be scheduled is not coming from any GUI event rather it will be changed in DB manually So what should be the trigger point for the task scheduler to stop current thread and read the new value to schedule the next job

Comment: Hi @Dhiraj  , I edited the answer . Please check and if its clear choose as rigth answer

Comment: Hi @vipin cp I know this process how to schedule the job using taskScheulder and scheduled future object but in the second point as you said: "if your DB cronExp value changed then..." how come my program will know what value of cronExp is changed in DB and it needs to cancel the previous job will my ScheduledFuture object hold the old cronExp value and everytime to trigger the job I should take it from DB compare with previous obj and if its not same canel and reschedule like that..?

Comment: @Dhiraj Yes . That is the only way, unless framework has to provide provision to read from some properties file or something like that. You can keep a flag for checking whether the value has changed or not.